# How to control ARINC429 label over a single channel?

Tags: protocols, data-stream, arinc

I am using ARINC 429 protocol to stream 4 different labels over a single channel using Ballard device.

BTI SDK provides the way to pause/resume/stop the channels but I am not finding any direct way to pause any particular label over the channel? Is there any workaround for this to make it work?

I am mainly looking for any functions provided by BTI42964.DLL?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. We have to use the skip bit in order to skip the messages. We can use BTI429_MsgMultiSkipWr or BTI429_CmdSkipWr methods in order to skip those labels.